# JSP generate file without starting empty line

Tags: java, xml, jsp, download

well I have a simple JSP-file in which I output a XML/XHTML document, so that you can download it.

```
<%    
String filename = "FILENAME.<XML/XHTML>";  
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");   

java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream(FILEPATH);  

int i;
while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
out.write(i);   
}   
fileInputStream.close();   
%>
```

The problem is, that the downloaded files always have as first line an empty line. Because they are XML/XHTML files, they are marked as not valid.
If I delete the first line, the files are valid.

My Question is, if anyone has a better solution how to download a file with a JSP or output the file without an empty first line?

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFqMP.jpg maybe this helps to understand the problem better. The yellow marked line is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the original files don't have the empty line as well?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. The original files are valid, therefore w/o the empty line

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was quite simple.

Instead of

```
out.write()
```

you have to use an java.io.OutputStream.

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(FILEPATH);
ava.io.OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;

while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

fileInputStream.close();
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

This works fine for me.